# Why is my JOOMLART UBER navigation menu displayed incorrectly on iPad in landscape mode?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, navigation, joomlart

The navigation menu on all devices tested works as expected in portrait and in landscape mode, except on one of our iPads.
This issue can be observed with an older iPad. With the newer ones, or with the iPad Pros it works fine again in landscape mode. The portrait mode works fine on all devices.

On an older iPad the navigation menu that appears on landscape mode is nothing we designed or expected.
It should be a hamburger menu, but it is a static navigation bar, that doesn't work.

All input is much appreciated.

[How the navigation menu should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcX62.jpg)

[How it actually is in landscape mode on an old iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx8cF.jpg)

Comment: My first guess would be that parts of the css or javascript failed to load or was incorrectly cached.

Comment: I think you should ask this question to the template provider to get a better support

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be the @media query in the CSS is having trouble with handling or identifying the older device.

A quick google search shows up plenty of sites with different examples for the various models of the iPad but they seem to come down to pixel ratio 1 for the older devices and pixel ratio 2 for the newer ones.

Perhaps post up some examples of the CSS in use.

Terry